# Read multiple files from concatenated gzip in Python

Tags: python, compression, gzip

If I have a gzipped file and I concatenate it together with another gzipped file, is it possible to read the files separately in python?

Ex:

`cat f1.csv.gz f2.csv.gz > f3.csv.gzip`

I know this is possible in Go, but is there a way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use `z = zlib.decompressobj(31)`, and then use `z` to decompress until `z.unused_data` is not empty, or you have processed all of the input. If you get `z.unused_data` as not empty, then it contains the start of the next gzip stream. Create a new `y = zlib.decompressobj` object, and start decompression with the contents of `z.unused_data`, continuing with more data from the file.

This prints the uncompressed size of each concatenated gzip component:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import zlib
z = zlib.decompressobj(31)
count = 0
while True:
    if z.unused_data == "":
        buf = sys.stdin.read(8192)
        if buf == "":
            break
    else:
        print count
        count = 0
        buf = z.unused_data
        z = zlib.decompressobj(31)
    got = z.decompress(buf)
    count += len(got)
print count
```

Comment: I found this answer very helpful--thanks! But I think it contains a subtle bug: what if several small files are compressed within a single 8K block? This code will only decompress the first one, each time through the loop. True?

Comment: No. The buffer size doesn't matter. If a 20-byte gzip stream is at the start of the 8192 bytes, then the remaining 8172 bytes will be left in `z.unused_data`. You could just try it and see that it works.

Comment: You're right, I looked more closely and indeed it does decompress multiple files within a single block.

Comment: @MarkAdler I ran into an issue using this if the gzip'd file was larger than buffer size. It would surprisingly decompress the partial file without raise an error

Comment: You mean larger than 8192? No, it will decompress the whole thing. What do you mean "partial file"?

Comment: @MarkAdler It will decompress everything, but you can't tell where 1 original file ends and the next begins. I made a simple script to demonstrate the problem [here](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZi948kZ2qOCctvnsAVofxdDmfuJcY89FU8k). Side note: thanks for taking the time to share your enormous wealth of knowledge

Comment: If you want to do something special between the gzip members, then you would do that in your `get_zipped_objs()` after the `else:`.

Comment: @MarkAdler yeah it's just that if the chunksize is less than the gzipped file size it unzips it in segments and you end up with 10 objects instead of the original 2. I was thinking of searching for the gzip footer (/x0 I think) before attempting to decompress

Comment: Objects? I don't know what you mean. In any case, that `else:` clause is executed only once for your test case with two gzip members. Not nine times. If you want to generate a separate output for each gzip member that precedes the last one, then write out what you have so far in that `else:` clause. Write out the last member from you have so far at the end.

Comment: @MarkAdler Apologies for my ambiguous wording. In your example, if sys.stdin.read size is 1 and the gzip file size is 2, it will call decompress twice and return 2 unzipped files instead of the original 1. (I probably should have started a new question at this point)

Comment: Yes, this needs a new question.

Answer (score 0):

@MarkAdler
Thank you very much for this answer. It actually helped me quite a bit !

Now I just want to add a tiny detail that can save a lot of your time. The current answer will not detect truncated files such as gzip/zcat would.

```
zcat file.gz 
gzip: file.gz: unexpected end of file
```

To correct this, check [decompress.oef](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.Decompress.eof). If False, this means the gzip file is truncated. If you don't do this, you'll never see an error.

Here is the modified code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import zlib
z = zlib.decompressobj(31)
count = 0
while True:
    if z.unused_data == "":
        buf = sys.stdin.read(8192)
        if buf == "":
            # check truncated file
            if not z.eof:
                raise RuntimeError("unexpected end of file")
            break
    else:
        print count
        count = 0
        buf = z.unused_data
        z = zlib.decompressobj(31)
    got = z.decompress(buf)
    count += len(got)
print count
```